# Paypal SetExpressCheckout digital goods

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

im work on paypal api soap method. On go to live mode i have a problem with digital goods. We sell virtual currency. On paypal setExpressCheckout i got error:

> You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.

found solution to set bussiness account type to **Digital Goods Express Checkout** but option is not avaliable. How i can set expresscheckout with digital goods?

Answer (score 1):

[Contact PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/) and let them know what you're doing.  They need to enable Digital Goods for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all countries support PayPal Digital Goods. If it is available in your country, you can find it in "My business setup" in "Selling Tools" page. Here are the steps. For more information, you can check here:

http://tutorial.joompolitan.com/faq/1-faq-paypal-digital-goods-for-joomla.html

[image: Make sure your account type is Business]
[image: Go to selling tools]
[image: Change payment solution]